# Appending to a file using C#

Tags: c#

```
 StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/abc.txt"));
Stream stream1 = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync();
StreamWriter sr1 = new StreamWriter(stream1);
```

It worked fine with StreamReader.
It had an exception saying

```
   Access denied due to security concerns.
```

How to correct this code?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Store the file in a location where you have write rights.